# Python 3.11 не хочет добавляться в систему Path

Tags: python, файловые-пути

Установил python 3.11, добавил в системы, а также в системы path. Но ничего не работает, выводит ошибку. Что я сделал не так? Как исправить?

> C:\Users\Admin>python
> 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

> C:\Users\Admin>python
> 'python' не распознается как внутренняя или внешняя команда,
> как внутренняя или внешняя команда или пакетный файл.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы папку с ярлыками пытаетесь в PATH добавить (обратите внимание на то, что в колонке "тип" указано на первом скриншоте). Нужно добавлять папку, где python.exe лежит.

Comment: И переменная окружения называется Path, она уже существует, нужно в ее начало добавлять путь, отделять от остальных записей точкой с запятой (без пробелов справа или слева от точки с запятой).

Comment: Спасибо, я исправил, всё работает.